# StaticArrays and Statsbase

Tags: julia

I want to use `StaticArray` with `StatsBase`. Consider the following function

```
function update_weights_1(N, M)
    weights_vector_to_update      = ones(N) / N

    wvector = Weights(weights_vector_to_update, 1)

    res = [0.0]
    for m in 1:M
        sample!(M_vector, wvector, res)
    end
end

function update_weights_2(N, M)
    weights_vector_to_update      = ones(N) / N

    res = [0.0]
    for m in 1:M
        sample!(M_vector, Weights(weights_vector_to_update, 1), res)
    end
end
```

`update_weights_1` requires substantially less memory allocation than `update_weights_2` because `Weights(weights_vector_to_update, 1)` needs memory allocation. However, suppose I have a list of small vectors, say `z`,

`z = [ones(3) / 3 for i in 1:10000]`

and this function

```
function update_weights_3(z,M)

    N   = size(z[1],1)
    M_vector = 1:N
    for i in 1:size(z,1)
        rand!(z[i])
        res = [0.0]
        for m in 1:M
            sample!(M_vector, Weights(z[i]), res)
        end
    end
end
```

`update_weights_3(z,1000)` allocates a lot of memory. I know that using `StaticArrays` for `z` can significantly speed up the code and reduce memory allocation. However, following the procedure in this [post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/memory-allocations-in-for-loop-variable/14332/2), whenever I wrap `Weights` around a `StaticArray`, it creates memory.

Would you know how to apply `StaticArray` in this case? Essentially I have a collection of small arrays that I would like to transform into `Weights`.

Comment: It's hard to suggest improvements to your code, because it seems to do a lot of unnecessary work. Why is it sampling into `res` over and over, overwriting its previous work? Can you reduce the code to a minimal example? In particular, don't add extra loops for purposes of benchmarking, that just confuses the reader. And make sure to clarify what your code should return. Make sure your function cannot be replaced by `update_weights() = nothing`, which is in fact the case now.

Comment: As @DNF explained, your function returns nothing and the inner loop just repeats the same calculation. Furthermore, `res` is loop invariant and `Weights(z[i])` is also loop invariant, move them out of their loops and you'll get rid of most allocations and speed up the code by 2X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Weights` is a mutable type, which can cause unnecessary heap allocations (sometimes they are stack allocated... I don't fully understand when this optimization happens). You can define your own immutable weights type, though:

```
struct StaticWeights{S<:Real, T<:Real, N, V<: StaticVector{N, T}} <: AbstractWeights{S, T, V}
    values::V
    sum::S
end
StaticWeights(values) = StaticWeights(values, sum(values))
```

Used in your example:

```
function update_weights_3(z,M)
    N   = size(z[1],1)
    M_vector = 1:N
    for i in 1:size(z,1)
        rand!(z[i])
        res = [0.0]
        for m in 1:M
            sample!(M_vector, StaticWeights(z[i]), res)
        end
    end
end
```

With this change I don't see any allocations in the inner loop.